# Unlist list in r row wise

Tags: r, list

Is there any way to unlist in R flattening in a row wise way?

i.e if my list were

```
[[1]]
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "2498" "A" 
[2,] "2346" "B" 
[3,] "2073" "B" 
[4,] "404"  "C"
```

Flatten the list to:

```
"2498", "A" ,"2346" ,"B" ,"2073" ,"B" "404" , "C"
```

Instead of what happens in a call to unlist :

```
"2498" "2346" "2073" "404"  "A"    "B"    "B"    "C"
```

dput of data:

```
list(structure(c("2498", "2346", "2073", "404", "A", "B", "B", 
"C"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L)))
```

Comment: `c(t(lst[[1]]))`

Comment: @RonakShah This approach doesn't unlist.

Comment: It does "unlist" but doesn't use the function `unlist`. It gives you the expected output shown in the post. If that is not what you want can you make your question more clear and show an example where this approach fails? If you have got lists of lists then you might need to use `sapply`, `c(sapply(lst, t))`